# How can I get MaterialSwitch id from activity in fragment in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How can I get materialSwitch id in fragment from activity. switch which is in mainActivity but i want to check in fragment whether the switch is on or off. for example "if(switchMaterial.ischecked){
code...
}" by calling the id from the mainActivity in fragment

I have tried this but it doesn't worked

MainActivity.java

```
    public SwitchMaterial switchMaterial;
```

Fragment.java

```
 if (((MainActivity) getActivity()).switchMaterial.isChecked()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "not checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Is this possible to call id from activity to fragment. If possible please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this on your way

MainActivity.java

```
static SwitchMaterial switchMaterial;
```

Fragment.java

```
if (MainActivity.switchMaterial.isChecked()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "not checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This should work but can make memory leak in some cases .. You may also try using SharedPreferences for example to avoid memory leaks

Comment: Thanks for giving me a solution but I have got one simple solution.....just I have called the id from activity directly "mSwitch = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toggel);"